# Change printer for a specific map document from Arcpy

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, mxd

Is it possible to change the printer for a particular map document from ArcPy? The mxd is saved with the default printer settings, and I know with the [PrintMap()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/PrintMap/00s300000037000000/) function one can specify the printer to use. In my case, I do not want to print the map, just change the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to do this, the [ListPrinterNames()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/00s3/00s30000000w000000.htm) function can return a list of printers but there does not seem to be anywhere to save a selected printer that does not involve printing.

I had a look at editing the mxd file manually or with some software, but its a binary format so I had no luck. I found some information about editing mxd files mainly around [version 9.3](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/doc/5a6ae887-c141-4616-bab3-167ccc5c0ed3.htm) which may be useful but I only have access to 10.1 so I cannot test them, however I am not sure whether a default printer parameter even exists to be changed.

Comment: Also, I think this functionality may be present in qgis, as I think it has plain text map document files. Although someone who knows more about Quantum can put me right.

Comment: It does seem strange though, that one cannot change the printer in this way. I have 10.0 and 10.1 available.

Comment: After some additional "fiddling" with settings and arcpy, this does not seem possible (or at least not "obvious") to do via Python.